# How can I have a chain of volley requests with progress bar updates

Tags: android, asynchronous, progress-bar, android-volley, chaining

I have multiple HTTP (JSON object) requests that I'm using volley for.  Originally I had them all fire at once.  Now I have them chained, like when one request gets a response and does the another request and on and on.  The listing would be too long to show here, but here is a simplified example:

```
//first request
    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
        {
//second request
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
//another request here...
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Log.e("Volley Error", error.toString());
                }
            })
//first request continues
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            Log.e("Volley Error", error.toString());
        }
    })
```

I want a progress bar to show xx percent after each response.  I have tried `runOnUIThread` and tried wrapping the entire code block in an 'AsyncTask' using 'onProgressUpdate'.  But it won't work.

How can I properly incorporate a progress update?

Comment: simply use 10 sync sequential volley requests in the background thread (or `AsyncTask`) - more http://belvi.xyz/posts/Using-Volley

Comment: I don't think that you read my question fully! I know how to make a volley request.  I want to know how to incorporate a progress bar that shows updates for each...

Comment: so you want continuous progress update (as the bytes are read from the wire) and not just 10 steps in overall progress?

Comment: ok i found  [this volley faq](https://github.com/google/volley/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) and it seems that you cannot have continuous progress update - so as i said: run your volley **sync** requests in a loop - exactly like in that [code snippet](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#usage) - here instead of `totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);` call your sync volley request

Comment: thanks that makes sense!  If you can make it as an answer, I can mark as correct.

Comment: btw if you want continuous progress update, then switch to okhttp/retrofit - volley is here a lame tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use a mathematical expression that didn't work - so the progress bar didn't move.

When I substituted the simple equation (below) for a number, it worked fine.

I set a variable to the total number of requests.  I wanted to pass the percentage for each, so I tried `(1 / num) * 100`.  Then I realized it was treating it like an integer, so I added `(float)` to the front.  With debug I found that the part in brackets equated fine as expected.  But the `* 100` didn't work.